# Dynamically create TextBoxes, adding an extra one each time the user clicks a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to dynamically create TextBoxes in ASP.NET, my code isn't working the way I expect it to...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
public int TextBoxCount
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["tbCount"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["tbCount"] = 0;
        }
        return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["tbCount"]);
    }
    set
    {
        int viewState = TextBoxCount;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out viewState))
        {
            ViewState["tbCount"] = value;
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxCount == 0)
    {
        AddTextBox();
    }
    else
    {
        RecreateTextBoxes();
    }
}

private void AddTextBox()
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "tb" + TextBoxCount++;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
}

private void RecreateTextBoxes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tb" + i;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTextBox();
}


protected void btnDisplayText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("tb" + i);

        if (tb != null)
        {
            lblText.Text += "," + tb.Text;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" />
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnDisplayText" runat="server" Text="Display Text" onclick="btnDisplayText_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is dynamically create a new TextBox each time the user clicks the `btnAdd` button. The `btnDisplayText` button should then concatenate all of the text in each TextBox and display it in `lblText`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you let us know what is happening - even though it's not what you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("tb" + i);
```

instead of

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("tb" + i);
```

in `btnDisplayText_Click`.

Also, remove all code except `ViewState["tbCount"] = value;` from `TextBoxCount` setter.

**Update:**

`ViewState` is not available in `Page_Init`. Move your `Page_Init` code to `Page_Load`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this still doesn't work. I want to be able to add infinite TextBoxes with the Add button, this code doesn't change the behavior from my original code as when there's two TextBoxes, clicking Add again doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
int TextBoxID=0;
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

TextBox.ID="TextBox"+TextBoxID.ToString();

btnDisplayText.Text +=textBox.Text;

lblText.Text=btnDisplayText.Text;

TextBoxID++;
```